# App Engine Python db.delete not working as expected

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Please help me understand what I must be doing wrong here.

I run a small video game on Google App Engine, and within the game we have an internal messaging service. Each message has a list of status keys that keep track of whether a player has read a message or not.

My problem is that when I attempt to delete a list of keys, only one of the entities is removed from the datastore, regardless of the number of keys in the list.

```
class Game_Message(db.Model)
  sender = db.StringProperty()
  recipients = db.ListProperty(str)
  status_keys = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
  payload = db.TextProperty()

  def add_status_keys(self):
    self.status_keys = []
    for user_id in self.recipients:
      gms = Game_Message_Status.create(self, user_id)
      self.status_keys.append(gms.key())

  def remove_status_keys(self):
    db.delete(self.status_keys)
```

What I have found is that calling db.delete multiple times **does** delete all the entities, but I don't understand why.

for example: This works correctly.

```
  def remove_status_keys(self):
    db.delete(self.status_keys)
    db.delete(self.status_keys)
```

Comment: You are more than likely running into Eventual Consistancy.  I assume a query is how you are checking if the keys have been deleted.  Try doing a get on one of the keys that have just been deleted to see if this is in fact the case.  And have a read of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: @TimHoffman woah, I added parent=message in the Game_Message_Status constructor and that seems to have solved this issue, but I'm still not sure wht calling delete on a list of keys needed strong consistency. I was using the Datastore Viewer to watch what was happening.

Comment: They will be deleted, you may not see that affect for a while, unless you use an ancestor query.  That is an artifact of eventual consistancy

Comment: Does the local datastore viewer really emulate this behaviour?  Entities that have been deleted hanging around for hours. (Or forever as far as I know)

Comment: You can check this scenario by just by calling `some_key.get()` on a key that you have just deleted.

Comment: yeah right. calling get returns None, and what's more, if you call get, the Datastore viewer will not show the deleted entities anymore.

Comment: Yes, thats one of the other observed behaviors of calling get() on a key , it resolves any eventual consistency at that point.